# spring sample webapp connecting with twitter

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, twitter, spring-social

I'm working on sample webapp that I'm supposed to show to my CTO.

It's basically a spring-mvc HelloWorld kind of thing whose only request is that users (in order to actually get to see "hello world!") need to login into it using their twitter account.

I find it amazingly hard to set it up.

I'm tangled among 2 different docs (spring-security and spring-social-twitter) and I'm now wondering whether I should actually go checkout [spring social oauth](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security-oauth).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few projects on GitHub that you can use for example code. The first is "Spring Social Security":

https://github.com/socialsignin/spring-social-security

This is a library you can use for implementing Spring Security using Spring Social as basically the "back end" system for your webapp's user accounts and login. There is a demo webapp using it here:

https://github.com/socialsignin/spring-social-security-demo

You may be able to just drop this library in, though I haven't tried it yet so I'm not 100% sure.

I also have a demo webapp that integrates Spring Social and Spring Security but a little differently. The idea is to add in Spring Social to an existing app that already implements Spring Security with its own user accounts and login info stored in a database.

https://github.com/sdouglass/spring-security-social